# how to get value from function and display in text widget flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, mobile

```
 import 'dart:async';
import 'dart:math';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: const RootPage(),
    );
  }
}

class RootPage extends StatefulWidget {
  const RootPage({super.key});

  @override
  State<RootPage> createState() => _RootPageState();
}

class _RootPageState extends State<RootPage> {
  int value = 75;
  Timer? _timer;
  @override
  void dispose() {
    _timer?.cancel();
    super.dispose();
  }

  void valuerandomer() {
    _timer = Timer.periodic(
      Duration(milliseconds: 500),
      (t) {
        int count = 0;
        int max = 1000;
        int min = 1;
        Random rnd = new Random();
        while (count != -1) {
          count++;
          value += rnd.nextInt(6) + (-5);
        }
        if (value > (max - 1)) {
          value = 999;
        } else if (value < 0) {
          value = 0;
        }
        print(value);
        setState(() {});
      },
    );
  }

  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Color.fromARGB(255, 12, 12, 12),
      body: Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
        children: [
          Stack(
            alignment: Alignment.center,
            children: [
              Image.asset('images/SQUARE.png'),
              Center(
                child: Text(
                  '$valuerandomer()',
                  textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                  style: TextStyle(
                      color: Color.fromARGB(255, 255, 106, 0),
                      fontSize: 90,
                      fontFamily: "MyFont"),
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

The output of the code:
[image]

I want the function to print every 500 miliseconds in the text widget so the value parameter starts with the value of 75 and changes every 500 milliseconds with this function. How do I do that? How do I declare this function in the text widget like Text('$valuerandomer')? cuz its just dont work. I tried just to type there $value but still doesnt work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You wrote that your value has to change but it's not really clear how it should change and what your `valuerandomer` tries to do.

My guess is that your are trying to randomize a number between `min` and `max`. And this should happen `count` times.

EDIT: This code now runs forever and changes the number.

```
 import 'dart:async';
import 'dart:math';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: const RootPage(),
    );
  }
}

class RootPage extends StatefulWidget {
  const RootPage({super.key});

  @override
  State<RootPage> createState() => _RootPageState();
}

class _RootPageState extends State<RootPage> {
  
  ValueNotifier<int> valueNotifier = ValueNotifier(75);
  late final Timer? _timer;
  final Random rnd = Random();
  final Duration duration = const Duration(milliseconds: 500);
  final int max = 1000;
  final int min = 1;

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _timer?.cancel();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    valuerandomer();
  }

  void valuerandomer() {
    _timer = Timer.periodic(
      duration,
      (Timer t) {
        int value = rnd.nextInt(max-min) + min;
        valueNotifier.value = value;
      },
    );
  }

  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Color.fromARGB(255, 12, 12, 12),
      body: Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
        children: [
          Stack(
            alignment: Alignment.center,
            children: [
              Center(
                child: ValueListenableBuilder<int>(
                  valueListenable: valueNotifier,
                  builder: (context, value, child) {
                    return Text(
                      '$value',
                      textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                      style: const TextStyle(
                        color: Color.fromARGB(255, 255, 106, 0),
                        fontSize: 90,
                        fontFamily: "MyFont"),
                    );
                  }
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

First of all we call valueRandomer to start the timer. The method itself does nothing else. The timer calls the callback function every 0.5 seconds. Inside the callback function we generate a random number between `min` and `max`.

The `rnd.nextInt(num)` actually just generates number between 0 and `num`. That's why we need interval shifting. Substract by `min` to get the range between 0 and (max-min). After that we add `min` back to number to get our real random number in our range.

Finally we set the value of the ValueNotifier to the newly generated number. ValueNotifier and ValueListenableBuilder are pretty handy in this case. The ValueListenableBuilder rebuilds itself whenever the ValueNotifier changes its value. We dont need to call setState here anymore because ValueListenableBuilder handles that for us.

Comment: Hello, Yes please, So I changed it a bit, I made int count = 1 and instead of count -- it would be count ++ because I want it to continue doing the task forever. int value = 75; and then a line below value = value + rnd.nextInt(10) - 1; but the thing is that it always stays in the 70-80 range it doesnt go more than that and I try to understand why but cant may you please help me with that?

Comment: Your while loop runs forever because you start with a positive count and you only increment count. It will never become negative, so your app gets stuck in the while loop. If you have new code then you should edit your code on this page. I edited my answer, so please have a look.

Answer (score 0):

It says `void function` because your function returns void type `void valuerandomer()` . Try changing it to `String valuerandomer` and return your value at the end of the function.